# Drop a non existing procedure in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-drop

I'm using MySQL 5.5.31 on fedora and I have trouble dropping a non existing procedure.
With the root user:

- Create a new database: test
- Create a new user: test
- Give all permissions to user test for database test

  ```
  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON test.* TO 'test'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
  ```
- With user test

  ```
  CREATE PROCEDURE test.foo() SELECT NOW();
  DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test.foo;

  Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

  DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test.foo;

  ERROR 1370 (42000): alter routine command denied to user 'test'@'localhost' for routine 'test.foo'
  ```

Why is the "IF EXISTS" not working?

If I do the same with the root user everything works fine (with warning, but that is okay):

- With user test

  ```
  CREATE PROCEDURE test.foo() SELECT NOW();

  DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test.foo;
  Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

  DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test.foo;
  Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON test.* TO 'test'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;` would not grant privileges to the user when connecting from `localhost`

You need to grant privileges for `localhost` separately

From the error it looks like you are disconnecting after the first `DROP` and connecting again from `localhost`.

Well, if you are executing these 4 statements one after the another, you should get the same result as you get with `root`

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON test.* TO 'test'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
CREATE PROCEDURE test.foo() SELECT NOW();
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test.foo; 
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test.foo;
```

Let me know, if I have made my answer clear

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I missed completely the part: You need to grant privileges for localhost separately

Comment: Firstly, are you trying to execute the 4 statements one after the other?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `SET sql_notes = 0;` before`DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS` command.